# How to quantify differences between sample means using ANOVA?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, anova

My problem is the following: I’ve run a one way ANOVA to test whether the means of my three samples are equal and found that there is a treatment effect. As far as I’ve understood, this only tells me that at least one of my means significantly differs from the others, but not which one and by how much.

Now, is there any way to quantify the difference among them, as in determining which of the means is the largest/smallest, just from the ANOVA, or do I have to test each of the 3 samples against each other to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow-up a significant one-way ANOVA you will want to do some post-hoc tests. These are tests that do pairwise comparisons between each level of your independent variable. I find that Tukey's HSD test tends to be the most common. You can think of these as a bunch of individual t-tests run after the ANOVA model and can give you p-values and effect sizes.

See [here](https://www.statology.org/anova-post-hoc-tests/) for an overview of the concept

and see [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spss-statistics/saas?topic=anova-one-way-post-hoc-tests) for a sampling of the available tests in SPSS